# NullpointerException override getview in arrayadapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to override the getview method like this:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private final Context context;
  private final ArrayList<DataList> values;
  private final  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());


  public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int    textViewResourceId,ArrayList<DataList> values) {
    super(context,textViewResourceId, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=li.inflate(R.layout.simplerow,parent,false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)   convertView.findViewById(R.layout.simplerow);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            Log.d("a","entre else");
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
       }
        DataList b=values.get(1);
        String c=b.toString();
        holder.text.setText(values.get(position).toString());
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

  static class ViewHolder {
      TextView text;
    }
```

every time i get to  `holder.text.setText(values.get(position).toString())` i receive the `null pointer exception` error. VALUES is a `arraylist` of type DataList and Datalist is my class who return two strings. I know Values is not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `holder.text` throws a NullPointerException is because you are using the wrong id:

```
convertView.findViewById(R.layout.simplerow);
```

So `findViewById()` returns `null`. Try something like:

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView); // I made up a name, but notice the difference?
```

Comment: XD thanks a lot it was driving me crazy LOL its really good some one else check your code because you skip things like this. thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: No trouble, sometimes we just need an extra set of eyes.